# How do I use for loops and data within a matrix to create a points plot within R?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have a question involving for loops and a points plot.

I have to use the measurements table (see below) to create a plot (see picture). My question is how do I use the for loops to obtain the plot? 
I tried creating an empty plot which can be used to put the data into but don't know whether this was the best way to go about completing the task.
I am very new to **R** so am not very experienced with for loops etc.

Comment: You should make an attempt and show what you've tried. Otherwise it is very difficult to know how to help you. Are you familiar with the `points()` function? Did you successfully make an empty plot of the right dimensions to fill in? (this is a good approach.) Do you know the syntax of for loops?

Comment: This appears to be an entirely artificial exercise. Using a loop to create this plot is far more complex than the alternative strategies.

Comment: Yeah I did an empty plot but it used the cell lines (column headers) in instead of the row names. I do know the points() function yes, but don't know how to link it in and I am not sure about the syntax of for loops.

Comment: It is an artificial exercise yes, I'm currently taking a R course module for data analysis.

Comment: But any data analyst would just use ggplot. I use for loops extremely infrequently

Comment: I've edited the question and added the code I used to try and make the empty plot

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
graphics.off()

windows(width = 10, height = 5)
#Empty Plot
plot(x = 1, y = 1, type = "n",
     xlim = c(1, NCOL(measurements)),
     ylim = c(min(measurements), max(measurements)),
     xlab = "Gene", ylab = "Value",
     axes = FALSE)   

#Add boxes and axis-labels
box()
axis(1, at = 1:NCOL(measurements), labels = colnames(measurements))
axis(2)

#Add points
for(i in 1:NCOL(measurements)){
    points(cbind(i, measurements[,i]),
           pch = 22, col = as.numeric(as.factor(row.names(measurements))))
}

#enable drawing outside plot region
par(xpd = TRUE)

#Add legend
legend("top", inset = c(0, -0.2), legend = row.names(measurements),
       fill = NA, border = NA,
       pch = 22, col = as.numeric(as.factor(row.names(measurements))),
       ncol = NROW(measurements), cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
measurements = structure(list(Kc167_1 = c(10L, 10L, 61L, 20L, 89L, 72L, 55L, 
62L, 70L, 89L), Kc167_2 = c(9L, 56L, 5L, 86L, 20L, 69L, 75L, 
27L, 75L, 99L), Kc167_3 = c(3L, 8L, 28L, 89L, 70L, 82L, 86L, 
26L, 76L, 74L), BG3_1 = c(47L, 3L, 98L, 53L, 84L, 53L, 8L, 18L, 
86L, 95L), BG3_2 = c(5L, 34L, 83L, 68L, 91L, 15L, 97L, 10L, 1L, 
6L), BG3_3 = c(93L, 1L, 57L, 87L, 70L, 84L, 14L, 59L, 61L, 25L
), S2_1 = c(55L, 54L, 83L, 38L, 42L, 5L, 1L, 95L, 72L, 33L), 
    S2_2 = c(74L, 85L, 83L, 74L, 1L, 73L, 67L, 6L, 22L, 24L), 
    S2_3 = c(96L, 18L, 80L, 79L, 6L, 8L, 84L, 63L, 34L, 27L)), .Names = c("Kc167_1", 
"Kc167_2", "Kc167_3", "BG3_1", "BG3_2", "BG3_3", "S2_1", "S2_2", 
"S2_3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Clic", "Treh", 
"bib", "CalpC", "tud", "cort", "S2P", "Mitofilin", "Oxp", "Ada1-2"
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for example, I really appreciate it. I am just trying to get head the codes. Is there a way to make the X-axis labels to be the gene names? As in the row names on the measurements table.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I will go away and have a long look at this. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm working on your code now. The problem is, I want to use more than 1 point style , as shown in the example. Is there a way to do everything at once?

Comment: I was trying to make a different style for for each cell line. By this I mean keeping the same point style for Kc167_1,Kc167_2 and Kc167_3. Then have a different style for BG3_1, BG3_2 and BG3_3. Then have a different style for S2_1,S2_2 and S2_3. So in all there will be three different point styles. Obviously, I would then need to make these correspond to the ones in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ggplot2 code which makes a similar plot

```
library(tidyverse)
measurements %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "gene") %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, -gene) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = gene, y = value, colour = key)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Gene", y = "Expression Level", title = "Expression Level") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```